# can grow text field with indent in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have created formula to indent a text field to displaying a tree structure,

```
Numbervar x;
Numbervar level := {Sheet1_.Level};
StringVar indentStr;
For x := 1 To level Do
(
indentStr := indentStr + '&nbsp;'
);
indentStr + cstr({Sheet1_.Name})
```

and also set the "Can Grow" property.

The problem is that when the data exceed column length,

**Output:**

```
FIXED ASSETS
    FURNITURE AND FIXTURE
        SUNDRY CREDITORS
    OFFICE EQUIPMENTS AND APPLIANCES AND PURCHASE OF 
BARCODE PRINTER
```

**Expected Output:**

```
FIXED ASSETS
    FURNITURE AND FIXTURE
        SUNDRY CREDITORS1
    OFFICE EQUIPMENTS AND APPLIANCES AND PURCHASE OF 
    BARCODE PRINTER
```

Is there a way to achieve?

Comment: HEading Fixed Assests is a different field or entire data is from single field

Comment: @siva,  FIXED ASSETS is first level of data not a heading.

Comment: One work around would be take 2 formulas one for Fixed Assets and other for remaining data now place the second formula by giving sufficient place space so that you won't get any issues

Comment: @siva, that's the issue there will be 'n' number of levels.

Comment: what does sheet1.level contains and how that is used in formula?

Comment: sheet1.level  is number, it used to generate no of spaces. eg: level 1 = 8, level 2 = 16, etc...